# Why TransformListener initializiton giving an AttributeError?

Tags: ros, tf2, transform-listener, transformations, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to transform a point from a map frame to camera frame.  But i was getting an AttributeError.
I followed this [api](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#tf.TransformerROS)
and wrote the following code.

```
target = "wide_stereo_optical_frame";
point = PointStamped()
point.point.x =2;
point.point.y = 1;
point.point.z = 1;
point.header.frame_id = "map";
point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now();                                                              tf = tf.TransformListener();                                                                        tf.waitForTransform(target, point.header.frame_id, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(5.0));
camera_target = tf.transformPoint(target, point)
```

In the above code, i was created a point in "map" frame and trying to transform into "wide_stereo_optical_frame" frame.
But, I was getting an error
tf.Exception:
AttributeError: 'TransformListener' object has no attribute 'Exception'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237125/why-transformlistener-initializiton-giving-an-attributeerror?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your line

```
tf = tf.TransformListener();
```

Is overrideing the tf module with an instance of a TransformListener.

Thus if any subsequent call to use part of the tf module will fail unless it's implemented in the TransformListener class.

As a general rule you should consider module names protected and not use colliding variable names.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-16**:
TransformListener initialization is successful now. But the above code giving tf exception. I am not sure where i am wrong.  Do i need to raise new question?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-06-16**:
Yes, please ask a new question. Make sure it's fully self contained as the people reading that question might not have seen this one. Before you ask your question though please make sure to read the tf Tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials that explain most causes of exceptions.